# Linking to a static lib compiled with MSVC

Tags: dll, rust

I'm trying to link with a simple C lib on windows against Rust library

My lib is .h

```
extern "C" {
    void say_hello(const char* s);
}
```

.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

void say_hello(const char* s) {
    printf("hello world");
}
```

My Rust file

```
#[link(name="CDbax", kind="static")]
extern "C" {
    fn say_hello(s: *const libc::c_char) -> () ;
}
```

Linking fails by giving an error with one of the data symbols

```
error: linking with `gcc` failed: exit code: 1
note: "gcc" "-Wl,--enable-long-section-names" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-Wl,--large-address-aware" "-shared-libgcc" "-L" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib" "e:\Rust\DBTools\DBAnalytics\target\debug\DBAnalytics.o" "-o" "e:\Rust\DBTools\DBAnalytics\target\debug\DBAnalytics.dll" "e:\Rust\DBTools\DBAnalytics\target\debug\DBAnalytics.metadata.o" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-11582ce5.rlib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcollections-11582ce5.rlib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librustc_unicode-11582ce5.rlib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\librand-11582ce5.rlib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liballoc-11582ce5.rlib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\liblibc-11582ce5.rlib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libcore-11582ce5.rlib" "-L" "e:\Rust\DBTools\DBAnalytics\target\debug" "-L" "e:\Rust\DBTools\DBAnalytics\target\debug\deps" "-L" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust 1.2\bin\rustlib\i686-pc-windows-gnu\lib" "-L" "e:\Rust\DBTools\DBAnalytics\.rust\bin\i686-pc-windows-gnu" "-L" "e:\Rust\DBTools\DBAnalytics\bin\i686-pc-windows-gnu" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-Wl,--whole-archive" "-l" "CDbax" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-l" "ws2_32" "-l" "userenv" "-l" "advapi32" "-shared" "-l" "compiler-rt"
note: Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Cannot export ??_C@_0M@LACCCNMM@hello?5world?$AA@: symbol not found
```

The library is build on MSVC2013 as a simple static lib. The string "hello world" is in the data section, so I wouldn't expect it to cause a link error. Are there some specific settings I need to be aware about when linking with C libraries on windows?

Btw it's 32bit MSVC lib.

Comment: What if you try to build the dll with GCC?

Comment: rust got msvc support a few days ago, but I don't think there are any msvc-nightlies, and I don't know how far that support goes. You can try building your own mvsc-rustc by calling `./configure` with `--target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` let us know how it went! related PR: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/25848

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, a few things.  First of all, there's no such thing as a "static DLL": a DLL is a *dynamically* linked library.

Secondly, Rust uses the MinGW toolchain and runtime.  Mixing MSVC and MinGW runtimes can cause odd things to happen, so it's probably best avoided if at all possible.  Rust has only recently landed *very early* support for building using the MSVC runtime.

However, you *can* get this *specific* example to work, apparently without any ill effects.  You just need to change a few things:

- You need to use a dynamic library; my understanding is that this makes bad interactions a little less likely.
- You need to *actually* compile `say_hello` with `C` linkage, not `C++` linkage.  You did this in the header, but not in the source file.
- You need to publicly export `say_hello` from the library.

Thus:

`hello.rs`:

```
#[link(name="hello", kind="dylib")]
extern {
    fn say_hello();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe { say_hello(); }
}
```

`hello.h`:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void say_hello();
}

#endif
```

`hello.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>

#include "hello.h"

void say_hello() {
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

`build.cmd`

```
cl /LD hello.cpp
rustc -L. hello.rs
```

On my machine, this produces `hello.exe` and `hello.dll`; when run, `hello.exe` prints out `hello world`.

Comment: I meant static lib, not dll.
Sadly our 'corporate' libraries are all written using MSVC so it's not really an option for me to change them. I'll give the above a go

Comment: @Ronnie, if you meant static lib and not DLL, you should probably update your question to reflect that. Currently it states several times that it is a DLL.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you for this, you're my hero.  Search efforts had implied that libraries like FFI or libloaderapi or winapi would be needed, yet a complete code example was not forthcoming.  With your answer, using a windows .dll from Rust becomes trivial and is supported in core.